# How to use <input> in a for loop in Flask?

Tags: python, html, for-loop

Hey guys I have some buttons in my HTML file in Flask and I want to return some other buttons as a response to each of the first buttons. For example, first, a user sees buttons for "Document", "suppliers" and "Method" and then when the user clicks on Document he/she will see 3 other buttons "Document 1", "Document 2" and "Document 3". For the secondary buttons I am trying to use for loop in Flask but it doesn't work.

```
{% if l %}
<form id="buttons" action="POST">
{% for i in li %}
<input type="submit" name={{i}} value={i}} class='btn btn-primary'>
{% endfor %}
</form>
{% endif %}
```

I just started to work with Flask and I don't know how can I fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use for loops as in this example, I have been using:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <form style="text-align:center;" name="goterms_id_select" id="goterms_id_select" action="/InteractionMaps/ByGene/showInxMapByGene/" method="POST">
        <label> COMPARISONs </label>
        <br>
        <select name="comparison_id_select" class="selectpicker form-control" style="width:120px;height:25px;text-align:center;">
          {% for first_selection in first_selections %}
            <option value="{{ first_selection.name }}">{{ first_selection.name }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <label> Gene NAME </label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="gene_name_select" style="width:200px;">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

you can find the page for this html [here](http://139.162.151.15/InteractionMaps/ByGene/)

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you?

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  // this function is strict...
}());

// hide btns by default
document.getElementById('hidden_btn_document_1').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('hidden_btn_document_2').style.display = 'none';

// Make the buttons visible only when Document btn is clicked;
document.getElementById('document_btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Show btns
  document.getElementById('hidden_btn_document_1').style.display = 'block';

  document.getElementById('hidden_btn_document_2').style.display = 'block';
});
```

```html
<!-- Three initial buttons -->
<section>
  <button type="button" id='document_btn'>
    Document
  </button>

  <button type="button">
    Suppliers
  </button>

  <button type="button">
    Method
  </button>
</section>

<br>
<!-- Hide these buttons by default
Only make them visible once Method button is clicked -->
<section>
  <button type="button" id="hidden_btn_document_1">
    Document1
  </button>

  <button type="button" id="hidden_btn_document_2">
    Document2
  </button>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if l %}
{% for i in li %}
<form action="" method="post" id="buttons{{ loop.index0 }}">
<input type="submit" form="buttons{{ loop.index0 }}" name={{i}} value={{i}} class='btn btn-primary'>
</form>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

By placing the form within the for loop you will unlikely have a conflict between buttons. You can also use hidden values (input type="hidden") at the other end you can then decode easier the hidden values along with the button name chosen that looks good on the page.